# Live Video Stream PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

I'm trying to create a simple video and audio stream for a *test* website. My aim is to do this in PHP.

There will probably only be 1 streamer ever if that changes anything.

I currently have set up a couple pages. The index is where the streamer opens their cam. It also posts the video source to a small script which will save the video source to a file.

The third page is where people will watch the stream from. It grabs the source url from the file and loads it into a canvas.

It all works fine until I try to load the video into the canvas. On the streamer's page, I do the same but it's only when I grab it from the file.

Current code:

**index.php** (streamer's page)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Voice Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
        <video id="v" autoplay muted="muted" style="display:none"></video>

        <script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var name = prompt('Hi, what is your name?');
            var video = document.getElementById('v');
            navigator.getUserMedia =    navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                        navigator.msGetUserMedia;
            if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log('Nope!', e);
                });
            }

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                var cw = canvas.width;
                var ch = canvas.height;

                v.addEventListener('play', function() {
                    draw(this,context,cw,ch);
                }, false);
            }, false);

            function draw(v,c,w,h) {
                c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
                $.post('stream.php', {src:v.src,user:name});
                setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**stream.php** (saves source to file)

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['src'])) {
        $src = $_POST['src'];
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $fp = fopen('streams\\' . $user . '.txt','w');
        fwrite($fp, $src);
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

**watch.php**

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['u'])) {
        $files = scandir('streams\\');
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $user = substr($file, 0, strlen($file) - 4);
            echo '<a href="#" id="' . $user . '">' . $user . '</a><br />';
        }
        ?>
        <script>
            var els = document.querySelectorAll('a');
            NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
            els.forEach(function(v) {
                v.onclick = function() {
                    location.href = 'http://localhost' + location.pathname + '?u=' + v.id;
                }
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Watch Stream</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <canvas id="c"></canvas>
                <script src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    var user = '<?=$_GET['u'];?>';
                    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    var cw = canvas.width;
                    var ch = canvas.height;

                    var video = document.createElement('video');
                    video.autoplay = 'autoplay';

                    function load() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url : 'streams\\' + user + '.txt',
                            cache : false,
                            success : function(src) {
                                video.src = src;
                                draw(video, context, cw, ch);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    function draw(v,c,w,h) {
                        c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
                        setTimeout(load,20);
                    }
                </script>
            </body>
        </html>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Is someone able to tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Streaming can not be done by using only PHP.

Comment: ^ you can do streaming in PHP+HTML5 (video tag).. or more traditionally, PHP+flash

Comment: that watch.php looks all wrong though, you need a url strictly for delivering the video stream content, not html mixed with a binary video file :p

Comment: @hanshenrik The content I grab from the text file is the exact URL used on the index page.